# CouchBase not restarting properly after disk extension

Tags: couchbase

I'm using CouchBase. We reach the disk limit three days ago. We extended the disk space but CouchBase doesn't starting properly : the web console is not accessible. The debug logs show the lies below:

> crasher:
>       initial call: application_master:init/4
>       pid: <0.86.0>
>       registered_name: []
>       exception exit: {{shutdown,
>                         {failed_to_start_child,ns_server_nodes_sup,
>                          {shutdown,
>                           {failed_to_start_child,start_couchdb_node,
>                            {{badmatch,{error,duplicate_name}},
>                             [{ns_server_nodes_sup,
>                               '-start_couchdb_node/0-fun-0-',0,
>                               [{file,"src/ns_server_nodes_sup.erl"},{line,129}]},
>                              {ns_port_server,init,1,
>                               [{file,"src/ns_port_server.erl"},{line,73}]},
>                              {gen_server,init_it,6,
>                               [{file,
>                                 "c:/tools/cygwin/home/ADMINI~1/OTP_SR~2/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl"},
>                                {line,304}]},
>                              {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
>                               [{file,
>                                 "c:/tools/cygwin/home/ADMINI~1/OTP_SR~2/lib/stdlib/src/proc_lib.erl"},
>                                {line,239}]}]}}}}},
>                        {ns_server,start,[normal,[]]}}
>         in function  application_master:init/4 (c:/tools/cygwin/home/ADMINI~1/OTP_SR~2/lib/kernel/src/application_master.erl,
>   line 133)
>       ancestors: [<0.85.0>]
>       messages: [{'EXIT',<0.87.0>,normal}]
>       links: [<0.85.0>,<0.7.0>]
>       dictionary: []
>       trap_exit: true
>       status: running
>       heap_size: 1598
>       stack_size: 27
>       reductions: 202   neighbours:
>
> [error_logger:info,2019-11-18T20:44:58.184+01:00,ns_1@127.0.0.1:error_logger<0.6.0>:ale_error_logger_handler:do_log:203]

I’m using Windows NT version 6.2 Server Editon. Build 9200
I extended the disk space by using a private Cloud Provider system. The disk wasn’t  replace. We just extended it.

Does any one faced tis kind of issue?

Comment: There is not enough information. a) how did you extended your disks b) what OS c) what version of Couchbase d) how many nodes.
This is unsolvable with the information provided